# how can make kendo ui numerictextbox don't lost formats when input value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

When i'm input values in kendo ui numeric, it's format has lost.

Example: 1,234,456 -> when focus show -> 123456

Can anyone help to solve this?

My code

```
 <input placeholder="UnitPrice" id="UnitPrice" />
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#UnitPrice").kendoNumericTextBox({format: "##,##0.###"});
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: `format` - Specifies the number format used when the widget is not focused. (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-format)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [kendoNumericTextBox API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-format)

> Specifies the number format used when the widget is not focused

I don't see any built-in way to accomplish this in a NumericTextBox... However, kendo also has a [maskedTextBox](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/maskedtextbox) input that may be a better fit for you.  In both cases, I think you'll have to build your own wrapper around the kendo component to get the desire behaviour.

Comment: maskedTextBox has size limit. As you need to specify the format  (ex: [##.##] ), then the input will be restricted to 5 characters only including dot(.) seperator.